# Url Rewrite get the error message HTTP errror 500

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use URL writing in the Web Server, after converting the URL provided by the user, and then passing it to the program processor in the Web Server. I have added `.htaccess` file in my domain folder root, like below the picture:

[image: picture1]

After I rewrite the rules in the `.htaccess` file, the error message is shown me:

```html
This page isn’t working
www.everyoneknows.com.my is currently unable to handle this request. 
HTTP ERROR 500
```

**My problem sample**

My website name which call is https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/customer/?loc=dashboard, this website is used PHP coding. I need to change last name ?loc=dashboard to dashboard. That means I want the result website name is https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/customer/dashboard

Below is my rewrite rules, but cannot work:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^everyoneknow\.com\.my [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/$1 [R,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^everyoneknows\.com\.my [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/$1 [R,L]

##External redirect to /customer/dashboard url rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/customer/?\?loc=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /customer/%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules to get it served by index.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^customer/(.*)/?$ index.php?parameter=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The result is shown like below picture:

[image: picture2]

If website name is `https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/customer/?loc=dashboard`, the result can run well:

[image]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: A 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error.  The only way to really know what is going on is to look in your web server's error_log file which should have better information about the cause of the 500 error.   The web server doesn't put this information directly into the page because it is something only the webmaster needs to know and not the visitor.  Without this information from your log file, it is very difficult if not impossible to answer this question.

Comment: "I have added .htaccess file in my domain folder root" - Can you confirm exactly where you have added this `.htaccess` file? It needs to go in the document root (ie. `public_html`). And `index.php` is also in the same directory? Is `/customer/` a physical directory?

Comment: index.php is also in the same directory. I put in the public_html/.htaccess